# Go language - import cycle not allowed

Tags: go

I'm struggling with a go environment I was working on, that stopped working.

No matter what I do I get this error:

```
import cycle not allowed
package main
    imports fmt
    imports errors
    imports runtime
    imports runtime/internal/atomic
    imports runtime
```

I tried just running simple code, and still not working:

```
package main

import "fmt"

func main() {
    fmt.Println("aaa")
}
```

Any suggestions? I'm clueless

Comment: There's something wrong with your go installation. Make sure your source tree is clean and show the environment variables you've set.

Comment: Show your go environment with `go env`

Comment: Never mind guys, I completely removed my GO environment, and re-installed it. Now it works fine.
Thanks!